# Custom Keyboard: How to Paste Image from pasteboard into messages.app MMS ios8

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, custom-keyboard, uipasteboard

Custom Keyboard for iOS 8.

Created the keyboard Target in Swift. Runs fine on device.

I copy an image to the Pasteboard like this:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "myImage.png")
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().image = image;
```

I have verified that image is indeed copied into pasteboard by manual paste into the active text message.

But I want to programmatically paste that image into a user's active message in messages.app (in MMS).

Comment: I was considering another approach to this. Is there a way to programmatically paste in iOS8 such as the 'command V' on a mac? Without worrying about where or what you are pasting. Probably not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried to create my own keyboard at the moment.

Nevertheless I use two keyboard on my iPhone that includes images.
Both of them ask the user to copy & paste the images into the message.

I might be wrong, but I guess this is an actual restriction.

**Edit :**

I can't find the documentation for that restriction.
However, here is a capture of PopKey Keyboard FAQ :

[image: PopKey Restriction FAQ]

Comment: Yeah this is what I am finding but I wanted to post the question regardless. There are rumors that ios 8.3 is going to drop sometime in mid-march, and that's when they'll have updates to their keyboard interface. Who knows, possibly this will change.